# How to infer unknown cell frequencies (effect of a variable) if table marginals are known and cell frequencies for another population is known?

Tags: conditional-probability, contingency-tables, population

I want to infer cell frequencies (or conditional probabilities) for a population table where:

1. I know the marginal totals but not the cell frequencies, and
2. I know the cell frequencies for a table of a related but distinct population.

Specifically, this is to understand the interaction between gender (noting US Census only has binary gender data), Bachelor's degree or no Bachelor's degree, and voter registration status. The ultimate goal is to estimate the cell frequencies for a registered voters table, knowing only the marginals for this table, but having the cell frequencies for another population, the US general population.

Table A: Registered Voters

|  | Men | Women | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Bachelor's** | ? | ? | 39.87 |
| **No Bachelor's** | ? | ? | 60.13 |
| **Total** | 47.43 | 52.57 |  |

Table B: US (adult) General Population

|  | Men | Women | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Bachelor's** | 14.36 | 16.28 | 30.64 |
| **No Bachelor's** | 34.30 | 35.06 | 69.36 |
| **Total** | 48.66 | 51.34 |  |

What approach would you use to best determine these unknown cell frequencies? I recognize iterative proportional fitting (raking) could be applied here, but the implementation I know requires working from a dataframe, which would mean having to simulate the data first. Is there a simpler approach?

Comment: What do you assume that the US census table tell you about the registered voters table? You already see that there are people with bachelors degree are registered to vote than in the general population.

Comment: The US Census table is instructive about the joint distribution of education and gender. It tells us for example that the odds of men having a Bachelor's vs. not having a Bachelor's is ~ 0.419, that the odds of women having a Bachelor's vs. not having a Bachelor's is ~ 0.464, and therefore that the odds ratio of the men ratio to the women ratio is ~ 0.902. It seems like an instructive approximation method to me to apply what we know about this joint distribution in the general population to the registered voters table, particularly the way in which it diverges from conditional independence.